# Laravel email data post issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I open my site without `www` and send email, it works fine, but when I open my site and try to send email it's giving error unexpected error:

The error only comes when I open my URL with `www`. Without `www` it works and email is successfully sent.

```
$.ajax({

           url: 'http://example.com/save_and_send_email',


           data:
              {
                  imgdata:imgdata ,
                  report_id:reportID,
                  email:email_val,
                  _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
              },
           type: 'POST',
            error : function (r, s, e) {
            alert("Unexpected error:" + e);
            console.log(r);
            console.log(s);
            console.log(e);
        } ,
```

Comment: Error here is resulting from a token mismatch as csrf token isn't shared across subdomain and domain. There are directions to resolve it [in this discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sharing-csrf-token-subdomain-domain).

Comment: You should use the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url) or [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route) helper methods to generate links in your frontend code. This should help you avoid such issues.